# How To Embed Microsoft Excel Spreadhseet inside an Asp .Net page? Just like Google Docs

Tags: asp.net, excel, embed

I am developing a web based application that requires extensive works on spreadsheets. The spreadsheets are already created and are updated on daily basis. I just want to open/embed the MS Excel 2003/2007/2010 Application inside my web page. It should seem like the application is running inside an Iframe.

Users can click on file name. It will open the ms excel exe file inside iframe, they'll use the spreadsheets just like using it when ms excel is opened inside desktop.

Please help.

Comment: Are you expecting the user to have Excel installed or were you hoping to embed Excel on the server side? Where are the spreadsheet files going to come from and (more to the point) get saved to? I'm not really sure all of this is possible with Excel.

Comment: You can only "open Excel" in your page, if every user has Excel installed. Google docs doesn't "open Excel", they built a spreadsheet app to work in a browser.

Comment: well, i will deploy the website inside a local server. it will run on LAN. so, i can install excel on my server machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're budget allows for it i would recommend not to re-invent the wheel and use a third-party component like [Aspose Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) which comes with ready-to-use Excel spreadsheet visualization and manipulation controls. Check out the GridWeb.

Of course there are a lot of other vendors selling similar components with asp.net controls too.

If you have more time than money you could use a free asp.net grid control like [RealWorld.Grid](http://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/) or a platform independent solution like [dhtmlxGrid](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml) (which is only free if your project can be GPL'd). This of course will leave you with a lot of footwork with the office interop libraries.

Comment: thanks Till. But is there any third part open source .net control for this?

Comment: As a more direct answer: I do not think that there are any free components with even remotely similar capabilities as mentioned paid solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Microsoft Word 2003 being launched within browser from websites developed in JSF technology. I couldn't find a free of cost solution to use MS Office in browser while being offline. And even online.

Answer (score 0):

Absent a massive amount of reinventing the wheel the best solution is probably to either scale down your product or get a pre-built solution such as Office 365 or Google Docs.  Think about what your product really needs to do. Do the users need to access all of the spreadsheet or just one particular section (range or sheet). If your users need to do everything with a spreadsheet, get them a spreadsheet program.  Don't bang your head trying to figure out wheel 88888.0, so to speak.